# How to start and stop a while-loop with an ipywidget interactive Checkbox?

Tags: python, python-3.x, checkbox, interactive, ipywidgets

i try to start and stop a while-loop with a simple checkbox. But i don't know how i am able to update the checkbox-state in the while loop.

Below you can see what i have, but when i uncheck the box, the while loop won't recognize it.

I searched through the interactive functions but have not found any function to get the updated state of the checkbox.

Hope you guys can help me out :)

```
import ipywidgets
import time

def f(x):
    while x==True:
        print("!")
        time.sleep(1)

c=ipywidgets.interactive(f,x=False)
c
```

Answer (score 0):

If you create the checkbox explicitly with:

```py
checkbox = widgets.Checkbox(description='click me')
```

... you can get the current value with `checkbox.value`.

Annoyingly, that's not enough to just allow your checkbox to halt the execution of a while loop. Once your while loop has started, it occupies the Python interpreter. There is therefore no space for the checkbox changes to be interpreted until the while loop finishes.

Since this is fundamentally a concurrency problem (you want to react to changes in the checkbox while also running a computation), you need to use Python's concurrency primitives. You can, for instance, achieve this with [coroutines](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html):

```py
import ipywidgets as widgets
import asyncio


class HaltableExecutor:

    def __init__(self, checkbox):
        self._checkbox = checkbox

    async def my_code(self):
        # This is your user code
        while True:
            if self._checkbox.value:
                print('running')  # put your code here
            await asyncio.sleep(0.1)  # use this to temporarily give up control of the event loop to allow scheduling checkbox changes

    def start(self):
        print('starting')
        asyncio.ensure_future(self.my_code())
```

Then, create and display your checkbox:

```py
c = widgets.Checkbox(description='click me')
c
```

... and start your executor:

```py
exe = HaltableExecutor(c)
exe.start()
```

The while loop will now run. At every iteration, we pause to give up control of the event loop with `asyncio.sleep`. The amount we sleep by is irrelevant, the point is to give control back. This gives the main thread an opportunity to deal with outstanding messages like checkbox changes. At the next iteration of the while loop, `self._checkbox.value` is checked again and so on.

Comment: Doesn't work. Printing value of a widget and it remains the same.
And "while True:" means that the while loop will never be broken properly.